# Airflow: how to pass template/macro to Hive script?

Tags: airflow

I need to  parameterize  my Hive script  to be called from  Airflow 2 times:

1. With current date {{ ds }}
2. With previous date {{ yesterday_ds }} or   {{macros.ds_add(ds, -1)}}

I tried:

```
my_task = HiveOperator( ...,
    params = {  'date': "{{ ds }}"      }
```

In my hive.hql:

```
SELECT {{ params.date }}
```

Currently the executable code   is:

```
SELECT {{ ds }}
```

It is the literal substitution of my param, the template was not expanded.
I need to have:

```
SELECT '2020-11-11'
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Since `hql` param is in the [templated_fields](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/ee544b4a92ce28607c792519ba6b660e93f50fca/airflow/providers/apache/hive/operators/hive.py#L65) you can just use `{{ ds }}` directly in your `.hql` file.

So your operator will be:

```
my_task = HiveOperator( hql='query.hql', ...)
```

and the `query.hql` will be:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE date < {{ ds }}
```

You can also write the query directly in the operator as:

```
my_task = HiveOperator( hql='SELECT * FROM table WHERE date < {{ ds }} ', ...)
```